# MySQL order by random but show distinct first 5 results?

Tags: php, mysql, random, distinct

Ok I've got 3 MySQL tables

Categories
Companies
Offers

I want someone to click onto a Category page, whereby they are shown offers from each company in a random order, so that no-one is given preference. A company can have anywhere between 1 and 10 offers and there can be any number of offers linked to a category.

This is all working fine but I want the top 5 (or more, whatever is easiest) offers to be displayed to be from unique companies. The others underneath can be in any order as long as they don't repeat those already showin in the top 5.

Not sure of the best way to go about this as it's a bit outside my ability - would it be to do 2 queries and left join them, excluding the offer ids from the first query in the second one?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Not really too useful as far as a solution, but the mysql RANDOM() sort can be incredibly slow if you're looking at larger datasets - just felt it worth a warning.

Comment: Thanks Simon, it's not a very large data set so at the moment the queries are taking less than 1/100th of a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a more efficient way of doing this but my brain is not at 100% today. How about -

```
SELECT
    company_offers.companyid,
    offers.offerid,
    offers.title,
    offers.offer
FROM (
    SELECT
        companies.companyid,
        (
            SELECT offers.offerid
            FROM offers
            WHERE offers.companyid = companies.companyid
            AND categoryid = '%s'
            AND active = 1
            ORDER BY RAND()
            LIMIT 1
        ) AS offerid
    FROM companies
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM offers WHERE offers.companyid = companies.companyid AND offers.categoryid = '%s' AND offers.active = 1)
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 5
) AS company_offers
INNER JOIN offers
    ON company_offers.offerid = offers.offerid
```

**UPDATE:** Added EXISTS to the inner companies SELECT

then exclude these 5 offer_ids from you main SELECT statement.

```
SELECT companies.companyid, offers.offerid, offers.title, offers.offer
FROM offers
INNER JOIN companies
    ON companies.companyid = offers.companyid
WHERE offers.categoryid = '%s'
AND offers.active = 1
AND offers.offerid NOT IN (comma separated list of 5 from previous query)
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: I was concerned about the performance of this query so I have tested it on my laptop with 1M offers across 2K companies and 200 categories and it returns in just under 0.2s. It is worth adding an index over companyid, categoryid, active on the offers table.

Answer (score 1):

Untested but something like this should work. Can we see your current query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT company, and, other, columns 
FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Nope I need to still display the other offers underneath it, so it needs to display all but have the top 5 as unique companies, so the same company isn't listed in the top 5 (unless there are less than 5 companies in the category). Current query just displays them all in random order:

SELECT companies.companyid, offerid, title, offer FROM offers, companies WHERE categoryid='%s' AND active = '1' AND (companies.companyid = offers.companyid) ORDER BY RAND()

Answer (score 0):

I used what nnichols suggested but tweaked (the initial query was taking 3.5 seconds to run for me for some reason) so I used this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT offers.companyid, offerid, title, offer 
      FROM companies 
      INNER JOIN offers ON offers.companyid = companies.companyid 
      WHERE offers.categoryid='%s' AND offers.active = '1' 
      ORDER BY RAND()) AS t 
GROUP BY t.companyid 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 10
```

Which is only taking `0.0088` to run. I then stored the offer id's being used and used the `NOT IN` from nnichols for the second query, it works great now

Thanks again for everyone's help :)